# Elasticsearch Query - Return All Fields But Limit Single Field Output to 100 Characters

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I'm working on extracting data from Elasticsearch (5.x) via python. When running a query I can get all of the data returned. However, I am working with a very large dataset and one of the fields can be massive (megabytes) which balloons the size of my output from what should be 500 KB to sometimes over 500 MB. Is there a way to return all fields via Elasticsearch query but for one specific field limit the output to 100 characters?

Query:

```
"size": 1000,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "query_string": {
                        "query": "level:ERROR OR WARN"

                    }

                },
                {
                    "range": {
                        "timestamp": {
                            "from": "now-2d", "to": "now"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

No. You will need to update the data in Elastic and split that field in two parts. One could have the first N characters, and the other field would have the rest, if there is any.

If you are unable to do that, then the best you can do is apply that limit in your code after you fetch it from Elastic.

Comment: Thank you. Another option I am thinking about is upgrading Elasticsearch to 6.7 which gives sql query capability. Through the sql-cli you can run substring functions.